# Spring security @PreAuthorize not working with embedded jetty

Tags: spring, spring-security, jetty

My application is having embedded jetty integrated with spring security for authentication and authorization. Authentication and authorization works fine for REST api calls to the application, but method authorization using @PreAuthorize is not working.

My spring-security.xml file has `<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />`
After some search I found that it is recommended to move global-method-security to servlet-context.xml under application context, but I cannot do it because we are not using "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet". We are already using "org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer" as dispatcher.

spring-security.xml

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">


  <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
  <http realm="Protected API" use-expressions="true" 
        create-session="stateless"
        entry-point-ref="unauthorizedEntryPoint"
        authentication-manager-ref="edbAuthenticationManager">
    <custom-filter ref="edbAuthenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/*/login" access="authenticated"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/*/clusters/*/datasupport/**" access="hasRole('data-scientist')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/*/clusters/*/job/**" access="hasRole('data-scientist')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/*/clusters/*/task/**" access="hasRole('data-scientist')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/*/clusters/**" access="hasRole('cluster-admin')"/>
    <http-basic />
  </http>


<beans:bean id="unauthorizedEntryPoint" class="edbServer.server.security.EntryPoint"/>
<beans:bean id="userDetailService" class="edbServer.server.security.UserDetailsServiceImp"/>

<beans:bean name="bcryptEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>

  <authentication-manager id="edbAuthenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailService">
         <password-encoder ref="bcryptEncoder"/> 
    </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="tokenManager" class="edbServer.server.security.TokenManager"/>

<beans:bean id="authenticationService" class="edbServer.server.security.EDBAuthenticationService"
        c:authenticationManager-ref="edbAuthenticationManager" c:tokenManager-ref="tokenManager" c:inactivityTimeoutSeconds="1800" />

<beans:bean id="edbAuthenticationFilter" class="edbServer.server.security.EDBTokenAuthenticationFilter"
        c:authenticationService-ref="authenticationService" c:loginLink="/api/v1/login" c:logoutLink="/api/v1/logout"/>

</beans:beans>
```

Relevant code to initialize jetty server

```
String SPRING_CONTEXT_LOCATION = "classpath:/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml";
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext parentSpringAppContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(contextLocations);
parentSpringAppContext.refresh();
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext springAppContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
    parentSpringAppContext);
springAppContext.refresh();

ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SECURITY
    | ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

contextHandler.setContextPath(CONTEXT_PATH);

GenericWebApplicationContext springWebAppContext = new GenericWebApplicationContext();
springWebAppContext.setServletContext(contextHandler.getServletContext());
springWebAppContext.setParent(springAppContext);

contextHandler.getServletContext().setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE,
    springWebAppContext);
DelegatingFilterProxy springSecurityFilter = new DelegatingFilterProxy();
springSecurityFilter.setTargetBeanName("springSecurityFilterChain");
contextHandler.addFilter(new FilterHolder(springSecurityFilter), "/api/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));

ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);
sh.setInitParameter("org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig", "JacksonFeature.class");
sh.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "edbServer.server.api.services;");
sh.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
contextHandler.addServlet(sh, "/api/v1/*");
HandlerList handlerList = new HandlerList();

handlerList.addHandler(contextHandler);

server.setHandler(handlerList);
springAppContext.start();
server.start();
```

how can I set global-method-security in app context here?

Thanks,
Saurabh

Comment: Can you show where you are trying to user @PreAuthorize? I hope you do know you have configured your app to be stateless, not relevant here, but there wont be sessions as such to speak of.

Comment: Judging from the code you have here you have the annotations on JAX-RS based web services. Those aren't spring managed so spring cannot touch them. You either need to use compile time or lead-time weaving with AspectJ to make that work.